# Plastic Spiral Vegetable Slicer Patent?

Tags: amazon, cn202723661

According to [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007Y9WHQ), [this product](https://www.google.com/patents/CN202723661U?cl=en&dq=utility+patent+is+201220380804.5&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_W7gUuCYL7SqsASc9oC4CQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA) is patented:

Why are there so many exact copies of this product found on Amazon.com under different brand names?

Is the patent not valid? Or is there a legal way around selling this product under a different name?

Answer (score 1):

The patent document you are referring to seems to be a pre-grant publication of an application for a Chinese Utility model. CN202723661 U. I do not see a corresponding U.S. patent. Even if it were a granted patent in China that would not affect anything in the U.S. Maybe the company in China is selling it to many branded distributors in the U.S.

Comment: Wow thank you for your fast reply! I saved your website to our resource list. This means any country other than China would probably be allowed to sell the exact product with another brand name?

Comment: A granted patent gives its owner the right to exclude others from making, selling, using or importing an item meeting at least one claim of the patent in the particular country that issued the patent. This specific patent document does *not* even represent an issued patent. It is the publication of the application for a patent. Note that there may be other patents in other countries that cover aspects of this slicer.